# Performing an action in Rails at a specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timer, ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

Is there a way to setup a callback in ROR that would trigger at a specific time?

Lets say I'm running a contest that expries at a certain time.  Lets say Monday July 28th at 9:00.  I'd like to set up an observer that ran a function at Monday July 28th at 9:00.  Does rails have a method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a run_at field in [Delayed Job](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). You have to have a worker process in the background always running and looking for jobs that a set to run, but if your application is doing this a lot, it might be easier than always writing new cron jobs.

So, you could have a method in your `Contest` model that gets called in a `after_create` callback that sets up a delayed job to send out an email to a random winner at the date that's specified.

If it's a one time, or very infrequent deal, though, I'll agree about using [whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: This will happen quite a bit, so I think Delayed Job might be best, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off writing a ruby script that runs via crontab at the exact time you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

I agree about crontab, but I like [whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever).  It has a nice integration into cron that you can store with your repo and it integrates nicely with capistrano.